# jQuery Color box, reload for two different function

Tags: jquery, lightbox, colorbox

I'm using jQuery Light box called Color box
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

There are three different function I made the different property but when I have multiple properties then reload function onclose doesn't work somehow for more than one. It works if I have only one onclose, but if I put two onclose, the color box doesn't work anymore. Why is this not working?

```
$(function() {
    $(".popup").colorbox({
    iframe:true,
    width:"35%",
    height:"55%",
    opacity: 0.7,
    onClosed:function(){ location.reload(true);},
  });
});

  $(function() {
    $(".popup_diary").colorbox({
    iframe:true,
    width:"750px",
    height:"80%",
    opacity: 0.3,

  });
});

   $(function() {
    $(".popup_icon").colorbox({
    iframe:true,
    width:"820px",
    height:"70%",
    opacity: 0.3
    //onClosed:function(){ location.reload(true);},
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you get any error in console?

Comment: it works on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/unqca2x5/), you can call _onClosed() callback function_ more times. if you get any error in console please notify us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code it looks like on the third function you haven't added comma after the last property before onClose which is breaking your code and it is not running correctly.

Comment: Waoo I was doing so stupid mistake, thank you very much!